# Which MediaRouter to use for detecting audio routes?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to detect (and listen) to which route the device is routing audio (aux, bluetooth, internal speakers). I see that Google has two MediaRouter classes, one in

> [android.media.MediaRouter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.html)

and another in

> [android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.html)

They apparently have different implementations of adding call back methods. Which one should I be using and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after reading thru Google developer's API guide here,
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html

It says:

> Caution: There is another set of media router APIs provided in the
>   android.media that have been superseded by the v7-mediarouter support
>   library. You should not use the android.media classes for media router
>   functions.

So I guess I should be using the v7, per Google's recommendation

Answer (score 0):

> Which one should I be using and why?

`android.media.MediaRouter` is API16+ while `android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter` is API7+ so basically it all depends on what is your application lowest supported API version, but even you target API16+ I'd consider going for support library  because of possible updates and bugfixes this version may receive contrary to devices' built-in version.